# why java streams skip method force to execute other operations

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In below code, secnario-1, map method never executed to produce count of my list. I understand this is lazy loading.
But in the second scenario, why map method got executed, just to fetch the count of my list? JVM just could skip 3 elements can bring the count without executing the map method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc1", "abc2", "abc3", "xyz", "xyz2");
        // scenario-1
        long count1 = list.stream().map(a -> {
            System.out.print("Map-");
            return a.substring(0, 2);
        }).count();
        System.out.println(count1);

         // scenario-2
        long count2 = list.stream().skip(3).map(a -> {
            System.out.print("Map-");
            return a.substring(0, 2);
        }).count();
        System.out.println(count2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I understand this is lazy loading

You don't understand it correctly. It is not "lazy loading", but a short-circuit operation. Executing `map` does not alter the fact the underlying spliterator is *still* `SIZED`, even after `map`:

```
boolean isSized =
   list.stream().map(x->x).spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED);
System.out.println(isSized); // true
```

unlike when you add `skip`:

```
boolean isSized =
   list.stream().skip(3).map(x->x).spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED);
System.out.println(isSized); // false
```

Comment: `skip` doesn't have to remove `SIZED`, does it? If you know the size before, you should know the size after you skip n elements, right?

Comment: @Sweeper true. The characteristics are optimizations. As a general principle, for example, if you write side-effects in a stream map operation you messed up. If you rely on these side-effects, you really messed up. The API of streams just don't make the kinds of guarantees that you'd need to write code like that, let alone that it rather sharply disagrees with the vibe of stream and co (which is rather functional in outlay).

Comment: @Sweeper in theory you probably are right, but then there would be people saying that `filter(x->true)` should keep `SIZED` also. It's a thin line.

Comment: @Sweeper this particular implementation has very little optimizations in this regard. The optimization for `count()` on a sized stream has been added in Java 9 atop the otherwise not very optimized implementation. Even for `list.stream().filter(/* unpredictable condition */).map(a -> { System.out.print("Map-"); return /*whatever*/; }).count()` there's no reason to evaluate the function at all, as its result is not relevant to the resulting count. Lots of room for optimizations.

Comment: Well, `skip` *could* (and should) keep the `SIZED` characteristic. Second, a `count()` terminal operation *could* (and should) skip all `map` operations, as they don't influence the element count. But well, these are optimizations, indeed, and no one is required to implement these, and their existence is grace.

Comment: @MCEmperor well, not all of them. It can’t skip `map` operations whose result get passed to a subsequent `filter` predicate.